# PHP Cut URL from some variable query

Tags: php, url

if I have some URL like these:

`http://localhost/myfile.php?start=2018&end=2019&page=1&status=`

Did anynone know how to replace any words from that link that contain `page=` ?

The result that I want is :

`http://localhost/myfile.php?start=2018&end=2019&status=`

Even if the link is like this:

`http://localhost/myfile.php?start=2018&end=2019&status=&page=3`

I still want the result will be without `page` variable and value, so it might be:
`http://localhost/myfile.php?start=2018&end=2019&status=`

any idea how to do this? Especially without regex (regex is my last option)

Comment: Is it a string?

Comment: Without regex ? It's very complicate and can't be sure to 100%

Comment: Is it a real URL or you are getting it as a string? agreed with @Inazo

Comment: Without regex I suppose you could tokenize the string, read it character-by-character and parse it out into a data structure based on those tokens, remove what you don't want, then serialize that data structure back into a URL.

Comment: why don't you want to use regex ?

Comment: PHP already has functions for [parsing urls](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [building query strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). Use them.

Comment: sorry, its a URL.. regex is last option, if it cant use only some basename function

Comment: @Blackbam oh sorry... can't find that before... that post is what I need! thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
// Your URL
$str = 'http://localhost/myfile.php?start=2018&end=2019&page=1&status=';

// Get parts
$parts = parse_url($str);

// Get array of arguments
parse_str($parts['query'], $args);

// Remove unwanted index
unset($args['page']);

// Rebuild your URL
echo $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'] . $parts['path'] . '?' . http_build_query($args);

// Output: http://localhost/myfile.php?start=2018&end=2019&status=
```

I encouraged to read documentation or to `print_r()` vars of this sample code for a better understanding.